# remove default hashing in Laravel 5 and jwtAuth for custom encryption

Tags: mysql, encryption, hash, laravel-5, jwt

I'm developing API with `Laravel 5` using `jwtAuth`.

`JwtAuth` returning valid token but the problem is `Laravel` uses hashing and against this hashing jwtAuth authenticate the user.

I want to use my custom encryption and I want jwtAuth to use my custom encryption rather default Hashing.

Comment: Please share the code snippets you have tried so far.

Comment: i have no idea from where i should start , my question is about idea for changing hash to encryption.